# How to write to csv file and attach it to email using Mail kit - Dotnet 6.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, smtp, mailkit

I want to know how to write my response - filtered Response to a csv file and attach it to an email using Mail kit. I can send an email with a body but I am unable to add an attachment.

//My Object

```
    var result = await _thunderheadReportRepository.GetMembershipOfferDetailsAsync(searchDate, cancellationToken);

    var filteredResponse = result.Select(o => new MembershipOfferDetailsResponse { CreationDate = o.CreationDate!, CorrelationId = o.CorrelationId!, PolicyCode = o.PolicyCode!, AnnualPremium = o.AnnualPremium! }).ToList();

    return filteredResponse;
```

//My email body

```
    var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();
    emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("email", _appSettings.EmailConfiguration.From));
    emailMessage.To.AddRange(message.To);
    emailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;

    var bodybuilder = new BodyBuilder { HtmlBody = string.Format("<h2 style='color:red'>{0}</h2>", message.Content) };
    
       
 
    emailMessage.Body = bodybuilder.ToMessageBody();
    return emailMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call:

```
bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add ("filename.csv");
```